# Looking for a solution to ingest Pega cloud service logs to Splunk using Splunk addons for AWS

Tags: splunk, pega

I am looking for a solution to ingest pega cloud service logs to Splunk. I cam across to approaches push and pull. With Push option splunk has blueprint lamdbda which can be used to push events to Splunk HTTP Event Collector (HEC). I am not finding any clear solution for pull approach. Can some one summarize for which scenarios pull will work and for which scenarios push will work.

Splunk and Pega Cloud services are on different vpc , how we can have secure data transfer between them.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple solution would be to set up your own client application to pull all relevant notifications. (https://community.pega.com/knowledgebase/articles/pega-predictive-diagnostic-cloud/subscribing-pega-predictive-diagnostic-cloud-notifications-using-rest-api)

You can run your application from your own secure server and have it write the info into Splunk. (https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/python/sdk-python/howtousesplunkpython/howtogetdatapython/#To-add-data-directly-to-an-index)